# jQuery remove and add class issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this layout:

[image]

I want to make the blue box sticky when it touches the header on a scroll **but** remove that sticky when it's reached the yellow box ( top part ) **but again** remove that sticky when I scroll up and reach the red box.

For the red box I have this:

```
 $('.sticky_ad_top_div');
```

For the Yellow box I have this:

```
$('.eevorg-widget-event-container');
```

for blue box I have this:

```
$('.subscribe-now-wrapper');
```

**I have tried:**

```
var event_top_space = $('.eevorg-widget-event-container');
var ad_top_space = $('.sticky_ad');
var window_width = $(window).width();
var is_home_page = window.location.pathname === '/';            
var sticky_ad_top_div = $('.sticky_ad_top_div');
var sticky_ad_top_div_height = sticky_ad_top_div.height();
var subscribe_now_wrapper = $('.subscribe-now-wrapper');
var subscribe_now_wrapper_height = subscribe_now_wrapper.height();
var window_scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();

if( is_home_page ) {
    if( event_top_space.length ) {

        event_top_space = event_top_space.offset().top;
        subscribe_now_wrapper = subscribe_now_wrapper.offset().top;                 

        console.log( $(window).scrollTop() );
        console.log( event_top_space );

        // Show sticky sidebar if width is 992 or more...
        // for the calendar part
        if( window_width > 768 ) {                      
            if ( window_scroll_top > event_top_space  && window_scroll_top < subscribe_now_wrapper ) {              
                $('.eevorg-widget-event-container').addClass('sticky-sidebar-widget');
            } else if ( window_scroll_top > subscribe_now_wrapper + subscribe_now_wrapper_height && window_scroll_top < event_top_space ) {             
                $('.eevorg-widget-event-container').removeClass('sticky-sidebar-widget');
            } else if ( window_scroll_top < sticky_ad_top_div ) {
                $('.eevorg-widget-event-container').removeClass('sticky-sidebar-widget');
            }                       
        }           
    }               
}
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]`  snippet editor and add a [mcve]

Comment: Instead of screenshot a working exaple would be great.... :)

Comment: I have pasted the dev site

Comment: @creativeartbd We want to see the code HERE. Once you remove the site, there is nothing for the next visitor

Comment: In my question I have put my code.

Comment: With code I mean [mcve] - I do not feel like eyeball debug your code